# How to configure Visual Studio Code C++ compilation for custom Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-studio-code

I have a very simple c++ project with my own Makefile that has such commands "make a.out", "make depend" and a compiling command "make submit", plus a "make clean" which deletes the a.out and any cores in the directory.

I want to configure my VSCode so that when I press run, I would see the result of "make clean" "make a.out" followed by "./a.out". I have already installed the C/C++ extension and had my gcc installed.

These are very simple command-line commands but I just can't make the VScode work. The error says a.out is not found. In my launch.json, I have below scripts

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I change the launch.json and how should I configure my task.json? Is there anything else I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Literally first google hit: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/#Makefiles

Comment: What about your `tasks.json`?